# Error on trying to execfile a script that contains a load_source

Tags: python, exec

I have three python scripts,`job.py`,`control1` and `control2`

The `job.py` file is part of a different project and assume that i have no permissions to modify it.

## job.py

```
...  
execfile(self.control, global_control_vars, global_control_vars)
...
```

`self.control` holds the absolute path to `control1`

## control1

```
import imp,os
a='path/to/control2'
imp.load_source('control2',a)
```

## control2

```
...
for i in tests:
    job.run_test('pax', test = i, tag = i, archive = ARCHIVE)
...
```

Now the issue.The `job` in control2 is in the namespace of job.py.When the code `job.py` is executed,I get the following error.

```
File "job.py", line 1170, in   step_engine
  execfile(self.control, global_control_vars, global_control_vars)
File "tests/linux-tools/control1", line 18, in <module>
  imp.load_source('control',a)
File "tests/linux-tools/pax/control2", line 22, in <module>
  job.run_test('pax', test = i, tag = i, archive = ARCHIVE)
NameError: name 'job' is not defined
```

(Path names have been shortened)

- Is there any way to bring the `job` into the namespace of the `control1` where `control2` is executed?

OR

- Is there a way to import code[`control2`] to `control1` just like pre-processing happens in languages like C/C++?That is,the code from the location gets "pasted" at the location of the statement.

Comment: Try adding an `import job` to **control2**.

Comment: Thats not quite possible as the `job` is an instance of a class and there are a quite a lot of properties added to the instance before the runtest is invoked.So invoking from a new object wont be the same.

Comment: In that case, if you can't change `job.py`, I don't see how you can access something in it from another script -- and I don't understand why you accepted an answer that requires changing it.

Comment: the file control1 was only changed,the `job` is accessible from `control1` from the way `execfile` was invoked.the `job` was added to the control2 in the way mentioned in the third snippet

Comment: the job.py uses execfile to run control1,which is supplied to job.py as a commandline argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change `control1`, then you can have it pass `job` to a function in `control2`, or to set `job` as a global variable on the `control2` module.

For example, with the files set up this way:

`job.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

job = 'hi'
execfile('control1', globals(), globals())
```

`control2`:

```
def run():
    print job
```

and `control1`:

```
import imp, os
a = 'control2'
control2 = imp.load_source('control2', a)
control2.job = job
control2.run()
```

Then running `job.py` causes `control2` to print `hi`.

Comment: The OP says he can't change `job.py`.

Comment: No,he did not change job.py,just the control1 was changed and it worked :)